# Moving files based on file name with powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to parse a file name and move the file to a folder based on part of the file name.

Lets say I have several files in a folder C:\SYSLOG\Servers and Firewall\Logs.  They are log files from several different servers or devices..  I need to move them to our NAS for archival.  Sample file names:

```
 Boston.North.Application.S01.120613.log
 Boston.South.Application.S12.122513.log
 Lexington.System.S02.073013.log
 Lexington.System.S22.073013.log
 Madison.IPS.S01.050414.txt
```

I need to move them to a corresponding folder on the NAS.  My folder structure looks like this:

```
 \\NAS\Logs\Boston North Application
 \\NAS\Logs\Boston South Application
 \\NAS\Logs\Lexington System
 \\NAS\Logs\Madison IPS
```

So basically I am wanting to parse the file name for everything to the left of the server (Sxx), and replace the . with spaces to create the destination folder name.

The files are not always .log files.  All files have a .Sxx in the name and xx will always be numbers.  If destination folder does not exist, then skip the file.  There are no subfolders in C:\SYSLOG\Servers and Firewall\Logs.

I think I am trying to do something similar to [powershell to move files based on part of file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117208/powershell-to-move-files-based-on-part-of-file-name)

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.  I have been looking at this page: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117208/powershell-to-move-files-based-on-part-of-file-name - But I do not know how or where to search for the Sxx in the file name.  I am new to powershell.

Comment: Then I suggest you try something yourself first and come back when you have a specific question about something you can't get to work. SO is not a place where other people write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Rely on the fact that everything in the file name up until the Sxx block is the destination if you just replace the `.` with a space:

```
# Retrieve the filenames
$Directory = "C:\SYSLOG\Server and Firewall\Logs"
$FileNames = (Get-Item $Directory).GetFiles()

foreach($FileName in $FileNames)
{
    # Split the filename on "."
    $Pieces = $FileName-split"\."

    # Counting backwords, grab the pieces up until the Sxx part
    $Start = $Pieces.Count*-1
    $Folder = $Pieces[$Start..-4]-join" "

    # Build the destination path
    $Destination = "\\NAS\Logs\{0}\" -f $Folder

    # Test if the destination folder exists and move it
    if(Test-Path $Destination -PathType Container)
    {
        Move-Item -Path $FileName -Destination $Destination
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above and nothing happened.  How is this searching for Sxx (S01, S02, etc.)

Comment: It's not, but since Sxx will always be the 3rd item counting from the end of the file name and split by `.`, everything up to and including the 4th item (still counting backwards) will be the Destination folder name

Comment: I thought that was what you were doing, but the Sxx is not always the 4th item.  I am using the IndexOf instead.  But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Final Version.

```
# Retrive list of files
# $sDir = Source Directory
$sDir = "C:\Temp\Logs\"
# Generate a list of all files in source directory
$Files = (Get-ChildItem $sDir)
# $tDir = Root Target Directory
$tDir = "C:\Temp\Logs2\"

# Loop through our list of file names
foreach($File in $Files)
{
    # $wFile will be our working file name
    $wFile = $File.Name

    # Find .Sx in the file name, where x is a number
    if ($wFile -match ".S0")
      {
      # tFile = Trimmed File Name
      # We now remove everything to the right of the . in the .Sx of the file name including the .
      $tFile = $wFile.substring(0,$wFile.IndexOf('.S0')) 
      }
    # If we do not find .S0 in string, we search for .S1  
    elseif ($wFile -match ".S1")
      {
      $tFile = $wFile.substring(0,$wFile.IndexOf('.S1')) 
      }
    # If we do not find .S0, or S1 in string, then we search for .S2 
    elseif ($wFile -match ".S2")
      {
      $tFile = $wFile.substring(0,$wFile.IndexOf('.S2')) 
      }
    # Now we exit our If tests and do some work

    # $nfold = The name of the sub-folder that the files will go into
    # We will replace the . in the file name with spaces
    $nFold = $tFile.replace("."," ")

    # dFold = the destination folder in the format of \\drive\folder\SubFolder\    
    $dFold = "$tDir$nFold"

    # Test if the destination folder exists
    if(Test-Path $dFold -PathType Container)
      {
      # If the folder exists then we move the file
      Move-Item -Path $sDir$File -Destination $dFold

      # Now we just write put what went where        
      Write-Host $File "Was Moved to:" $dFold
      Write-Host
      }
      # If the folder does not exist then we leave it alone!
      else 
      {
      # We write our selves a note that it was not moved
      Write-Host $File "Was not moved!"
      }

# Now we have a drink!
}
```