# Avoid removing part of name in filename when copying files

Tags: powershell

Is it possible change below code, so it KEEPS the filenames as original
(so also keeping the name before underscore) ? :

TIM_DV_ORDERINQUERY.SQL should still be #TIM_DV_ORDERINQUERY.SQL when copied !

It should still create Folders and copy the files as original explained.

Please see original topic for original problem/question ask by another user:

[powershell to move files based on part of file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117208/powershell-to-move-files-based-on-part-of-file-name/57851641#57851641)

```
$SourceFolder = "D:\queries\"
$targetFolder = "G:\queries\"
$numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.TXT).Count
$i=0

clear-host;
Write-Host 'This script will copy ' $numFiles ' files from ' $SourceFolder ' to ' $targetFolder
Read-host -prompt 'Press enter to start copying the files'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.TXT | %{ 
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$destination = (Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath $_.Name.replace("_","\"))

   if(!(Test-Path -Path $destination.Directory )){
    New-item -Path $destination.Directory.FullName -ItemType Directory 
    }
    [int]$percent = $i / $numFiles * 100

    copy-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination.FullName
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    $i++
}
Write-Host 'Total number of files read from directory '$SourceFolder ' is ' $numFiles
Write-Host 'Total number of files that was copied to '$targetFolder ' is ' $i
Read-host -prompt "Press enter to complete..."
clear-host;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot really test it right here and Code is just a copy of OG Post

```
$SourceFolder = "G:\queries\"
$targetFolder = "G:\queries\"
$numFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.TXT).Count
$i = 0

clear-host;
Write-Host 'This script will copy ' $numFiles ' files from ' $SourceFolder ' to ' $targetFolder
Read-host -prompt 'Press enter to start copying the files'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.TXT | % { 
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$destination = (Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath $_.Name.replace("_", "\"))
    $destination = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($destination.FullName)
    $destination = $destination.FullName + "\" + $_.Name

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination.Directory )) {
        New-item -Path $destination.Directory.FullName -ItemType Directory 
    }
    [int]$percent = $i / $numFiles * 100

    copy-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination.FullName
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    $i++
}
Write-Host 'Total number of files read from directory '$SourceFolder ' is ' $numFiles
Write-Host 'Total number of files that was copied to '$targetFolder ' is ' $i
Read-host -prompt "Press enter to complete..."
clear-host;
```

it just get the new Directory- Path an add the old filename as string after an "\" to it, done.

```
$destination = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($destination.FullName)
$destination = $destination.FullName + "\" + $_.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the original question, simply replace the `Copy-Item`

```
Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $Destination.Directory.FullName $_.Name)
```

and yield this result:

```
> tree /F
└───Test
    │   #ERIK_P1_EMPLOYEE-NY.SQL
    │   #ERIK_P1_EMPLOYEE-TX.SQL
    │   #JACK_DV_SALESQUERY.SQL
    │   #JACK_P1_PRODUCTQUERY.SQL
    │   #TIM_DV_ORDERINQUERY.SQL
    │   #TIM_P1_ORDERINQUERY.SQL
    │   #TIM_QA_ORDERINQUERY.SQL
    │
    └───queries
        ├───#ERIK
        │   └───P1
        │           #ERIK_P1_EMPLOYEE-NY.SQL
        │           #ERIK_P1_EMPLOYEE-TX.SQL
        │
        ├───#JACK
        │   ├───DV
        │   │       #JACK_DV_SALESQUERY.SQL
        │   │
        │   └───P1
        │           #JACK_P1_PRODUCTQUERY.SQL
        │
        └───#TIM
            ├───DV
            │       #TIM_DV_ORDERINQUERY.SQL
            │
            ├───P1
            │       #TIM_P1_ORDERINQUERY.SQL
            │
            └───QA
                    #TIM_QA_ORDERINQUERY.SQL
```

Comment: Also working like a charm. Thank you for the solution LotPings